# Rewriting a Subdomain with mod-rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, moodle

I have a project that uses the moodle library. I had to change the URL from moodle.example.com to learn.example.com, due to a client request.

I thought this would be an easy change, but alas moodle inserts all links and images in with the complete url instead of the relative url.

Is it possible using mod-rewrite to point all requests to moodle.example.com to learn.example.com and maintain the query string?

Example:

I want a request to: `http://moodle.example.com/course/view.php?id=2&topic=1` to go to `http://learn.example.com/course/view.php?id=2&topic=1`.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =moodle.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://learn.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Damn, faster than me. Try this cheat sheet for mod-rewrite: 

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Something is still redirecting it to the login page. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the apache rewrite rules, it may also be worth looking at the moodle documentation on migration:  http://docs.moodle.org/en/Moodle_migration

In particular look out for admin/replace.php.   This tool can help you to rewrite links across all text in the moodle database at the same time.